# Custom color pattern to use in Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, macos, interface-builder

I guys,

you surely know about the color `grouped tableview background color`(see the screenshot below) or the `view flipside background color`. You can find them in Interface Builder, and they are a sort of "pattern colors".

**Is there a way to create a custom "pattern-color", and use it with IB?**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is **+ (UIColor *)colorWithPatternImage:(UIImage *)image**, which come from this [apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIColor/colorWithPatternImage%3a). I remember some document mentioning about IB plug-in, but I has no experiment about custom IB plug-in.

As for me, I will use category syntax to extent custom color pattern for project.